# Querydsl generate entity from maven dependency

Tags: java, querydsl

I know, this is a know question, that has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158170/create-querydsl-metamodel-for-entity-from-jar). The answer suggests to use the @QueryEntities. But I did not understand how to use this annotation and where to use it. Does anyone have an example to show me this working? Or better yet, is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You should new a **package-info.java** file in your package

```
@QueryEntities(value = {BaseEntity.class}) package xxxx.xxxx.xxx;
import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities; 
import xxx.xxxx.BaseEntity;
```